# What is the meaning of "what's up chucks"?

Tags: meaning

The guy in the this prank [video](https://youtu.be/UyGn566odNo) starts with something like "hey what's up chucks"? [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/chuck_2)'s second entry for this word says it is a friendly way of addressing friends in Northern England. However, the clip guys do not seem to have a British accent. Is "chuck" the word in question or did I mishear it?

Comment: ***Chuck, chuckie*** are perfectly common terms of endearment in Northern England (so you'll often hear them as ***chooks, chookie***). Probably as much by association with similarly-used ***duck, duckie*** (more likely in UK SE) as anything else. Personally, I'd say ***chucks, ducks*** are significantly less common variants, but obviously there will be people who *do* use those versions.

Comment: The word used there is *choads*, alternatively spelled <chodes>; *choad* is a recent vulgarism for, literally, a short broad penis, extended to mean the perineum, and figuratively extended as a derogatory form of reference or address to a person, meaning a worthless person, a loser.

Comment: @StoneyB +1 spot on as usual! The guys in the video are definitely not British, certainly not by accent. You can tell it's filmed in the US by the benches at the bus stop and the licence plates on the cars.

Comment: As a distantly related aside, "up chuck" is slang for "throw up" or "vomit". Be careful of homonyms...

Comment: As pointed out he is saying "chodes" not chucks. He is using this vulgar term as a familiar and informal greeting. It isn't uncommon for young american men (often referred to as "bros") to greet their friends by calling them something offensive in other settings. I would avoid using anything like this unless you are extremely certain it is the proper setting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As pointed out he is saying "chodes" not chucks. He is using this vulgar term as a familiar and informal greeting. It isn't uncommon for young american men (often referred to as "bros") to greet their friends by calling them something offensive in other settings. I would avoid using anything like this unless you are extremely certain it is the proper setting for it.

by user **jdf**